# add cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

Please let me state that this is for a homework assignment and any help would be appreciated.

I am am writing a program using Eclipse (Juno) that creates a frame, places a ball in the top of the frame and places a row of buttons on the 'south' of the border frame. The issue I am having is in the class that adds the buttons, called Btns.java, I am receiving some errors.

Error 1: add cannot be resolved to a variable
Error 2: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
Error 3: Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token

The code looks correct to me never the less.

The code for the Btns class is below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class  Btns extends JFrame
{
    public Btns()
    {
        JButton jbtL = new JButton("Left");
        JButton jbtR = new JButton("Right");
        JButton jbtU = new JButton("Up");
        JButton jbtD = new JButton("Down");
        JButton jbtRd = new JButton("Red");
        JButton jbtG = new JButton("Green");
        add.(jbtL);
        add.(jbtR);
        add.(jbtU);
        add.(jbtD);
        add.(jbtRd);
        add.(jbtG);

    }

 }
```

Lab2.java Code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2 extends JFrame { 

        public Lab2()
        {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new Ball(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new Btns(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }



public static void main (String[] args) { 

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
    frame.setTitle("Move The Ball");
    frame.setSize(450, 700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to put a `.` after the function name? I'm honestly curious.

Comment: Mis-read the code in my textbook.

Comment: Again, don't add a JFrame to a JFrame. Again, read your book.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you answered that while I was updating the post. Worked great! Thanks

Comment: @KevinSchultz For your new code, look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have extra dots here before the method parenthesis:

Replace:

```
add.(jbtL);
add.(jbtR);
add.(jbtU);
 ...
```

with

```
add(jbtL);
add(jbtR);
add(jbtU);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That fixed it but created another error, this time in the Lab2.java.       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
 at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at Lab2.<init>(Lab2.java:20)
 at Lab2.main(Lab2.java:27)                                        I have posted the additional code above. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to be adding a JFrame to a JFrame, something I'm sure your book doesn't suggest you do. Perhaps your btns panel should be a JPanel and not a JFrame. You will want to read your text and notes carefully since you can't guess at this stuff and hope that it will work. The compiler is quite unforgiving.

Comment: @KevinSchultz Hovercraft is correct, you are attempting to add a the `Btns` `JFrame` to your `Lab2` frame. You cannot do this. You could make `Btns` extend `JPanel` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
add()
```

is a inherited method from the `Component` & `Container` class, so you remove the dots and choose the correct implementation for your case, See [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you even written a Java code?

```
    public Btns()
    {
        JButton jbtL = new JButton("Left");
        JButton jbtR = new JButton("Right");
        JButton jbtU = new JButton("Up");
        JButton jbtD = new JButton("Down");
        JButton jbtRd = new JButton("Red");
        JButton jbtG = new JButton("Green");
        super.add(jbtL);
        super.add(jbtR);
        this.add(jbtU);
        super.add(jbtD);
        add(jbtRd);
        add(jbtG);
    }
```

The dot is used as a resolution scope operator to indicate that something is a member of a class. `super` above indicate the super class `JFrame`, which has the method `add` derived from `Component`. `this` indicate the current object, which is of type `Btns`, which also has the method `add` derived from `JFrame`.

`this` and `super` are not necessary qualifiers in most cases, therefore the last two calls don't use `super.`

Also, if you are adding object of type `Btns` to your main frame, then you should  extend `JInternalFrame` instead of `JFrame`.

```
public class Btns extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
```

Then is constructor:

```
public Lab2() {
   JDesktopPane p = new JDesktopPane();
   add(p);
   p.add(new Btns());
}
```

Comment: sorry I wasted your time, that's why I stated it was homework, I'm still learning. Your solution worked as well, thanks!